# Foliations and locally free action of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional closed manifold endowed with a foliation ${\cal F}$ suppose that the leaves of ${\cal F}$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ are the leaves of ${\cal F}$ defined by a locally free action of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ ?

The context.

I have been recently studied to differential topology and its relations to affine manifolds. One of the result that interested me is the following result of Rosenberg. (See [1] Theorem 2.)

Let $M$ be a closed $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold endowed with a codimension $1$ foliation of class $C^2$ each of whose leaf is $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. There exists a covering map $p:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times S^1\rightarrow M$ and $\pi_1(M)$ is free Abelian.

For the proof of this result, Rosenberg in [1] quotes his paper [2] entitled action of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on manifolds which studies foliations defined by locally free action of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ on  manifolds. The corollary 1.3 of [2] shows if the fundamental group of a $n$-dimensional closed manifold $M$ is not Abelian, then every locally free action of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ has an orbit which is not simply connected. The theorem 1.4 shows that if a locally free action of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ on $M$ does not have compact orbits, then there exists a covering $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times S^1$. The Corollary 1.4 and the theorem 1.4 implies that if a $n$-dimensional closed manifold $M$ is endowed with a locally free action whose orbits are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, then the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$ of $M$ is Abelian. The remark at page 134 of [1] shows that $\pi_1(M)$ is free Abelian.

Certainly, if the leaves of ${\cal F}$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, there exits a locally free action of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ on $M$ whose orbits are the leaves of ${\cal F}$. I would like to know how to deduce this fact from the papers of Rosenberg, or another reference for the proof of this fact.

Certainly if orbits are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ there is a transitive action of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ on each orbit. How to extend this action to an actiion of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ on $M$ ?

[1] Rosenberg H. Foliations by planes Topology 7,  131-138 (1968)

[2] Rosenberg H. Actions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on manifolds. Rosenberg, Harold. "Actions ofR n on manifolds." Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici 41, no. 1 (1966) 170-178.

Comment: In general, you should expect obstructions such as orientability of the foliation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Please do you have a reference about that ?

Comment: I do not have a reference but it is easy to see that if a codimension 1 foliation of an orientable is given by a free action of $R^{n-1}$, then the foliation is cooriented. One can construct a simple example of a smooth foliation $F$  of $R^2- \{0\}$, such that  each leaf is diffeomorphic to a line and $F$ fails to be coorientable. I do not have compact examples though.

Comment: @MoisheKohan But $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ is not closed.

Comment: I did not say it is.